# Uniqueness of the coefficients of Harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

> **Harmonic oscillator.** Rewrite  $$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega+A\cos\theta
>  +B\sin\theta, A,B \in \mathbb R$$ as $$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega+r\cos(\theta + \alpha), r>0, \alpha \in
>  [-\pi,\pi) \in \mathbb R.$$
>   Show that unique $A,B$ define unique $r,\theta.$

I have a feeling that we have to use $\cos(\theta + \alpha) = \cos\theta \cos\alpha - \sin\theta \sin\alpha$, but I don't know how to apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may use that formula. Note that by letting $A=r\cos(\alpha)$ and $B=-r\sin(\alpha)$, we have that
$$r:=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}.$$ 
Then there is a unique point along the unit circle $(A/r,-B/r)$ such that 
$$\begin{cases}\cos(\alpha)=\frac{A}{r}\\
\sin(\alpha)=-\frac{B}{r}\end{cases}$$
with $\alpha \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: But doesn't show the uniqueness of $\theta...$

Comment: I think that the correct statement should be: Show that $A$,$B$ define unique $r$,$\alpha$.  Note that $\theta$ is a variable!

Comment: wouldn't A and -A then define the same non unique $r$?

Comment: @dxdydz : All pairs $(A,B)$ on the circle $A^2+B^2=r^2$ define the same $r$, that's why you need the angle on the circle as second identifying property. In total it is the transformation of the Cartesian point $(A,-B)$ into polar coordinates that you use.

Comment: Here the uniqueness is for the **pair** $(r,\alpha)$ (see also LutzL's comment).